# PHP Loop not select if exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

i want to ask if this is possible? counting an item as stocks by selecting its name and make a num_rows of the selected item and on the second loop the item will not be selected because its already selected on the first loop

**i.e.**

i have this table **products**

```
category,       name,     barcode
vegetables      apple     101010101
vegetables      apple     010101010
meat            chicken   202020202
```

i have 2 stocks of apple, 1 meat that is chicken

heres my code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
     $stock_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '".$row['name']."' LIMIT 1";
     $stock_res = mysqli_query($con,$stock_query);
       while($stock_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stock_res)) {
           $stocks_count = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '".$stock_row['item_name']."' AND category = '".$stock_row['category']."'";
           $stock_count_res = mysqli_query($con,$stocks_count);
           $stock_available = mysqli_num_rows($stock_count_res);
           echo $stocks_available; //output here is 2
           echo $stock_row['category'].'<br/>';         
           echo $stock_row['name'].'<br/>';
  }
}
```

the output is

**loop 1**

2(as the vegetables apple stocks)

vegetables

apple

**loop 2**

2(as the vegetables apple stocks)

vegetables

apple

**loop 3**

1(as the meat chicken stocks)

meat

chicken

how can i avoid the second loop?

im not a hacker doing SQL injection i have dignity. im building my own system.
everything starts from scratch.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: mysqli_prepare?

Comment: yes prepare --> bind --> execute

Comment: AND the JOIN sql syntax which would probably get all these results in one query

Comment: Actually looking closer, ALLLL those queries are on the same `products` table. I think you just need to go for a coffee and then come back and rethink how you are doing whatever you are trying to do

Comment: NOTE: The second loop is not actually required, as you use `LIMIT 1` on the query so there will only ever be ONE ROW RETURNED

Comment: It may also be useful to show us the output you would like to see [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the thing that i have 3 queries is too first select all its content then get the name that limit only 1 and then make a number of rows of that item thats how i get the stocks right? sorry thats limit of my knowledge i want to know more

Comment: thats the output i want just to avoid the second loop if the name of the item already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, It might help you.

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct a.name, (SELECT distinct b.category FROM products b
WHERE b.name=a.name) as 'category', (select count(c.name) from products c where c.name=a.name) as 'count' FROM products a";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
    echo "Name: " . $row["name"] . "<br/>";
    echo "Category: " . $row["category"] . "<br/>";
    echo "Count: " . $row["count"] . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

The answer is not tested for various cases. Please test it for various case scenarios in your project.
Start using prepared statements in future, Those are really easy and awesome. mysqli functions are deprecated.
All the best!

Comment: thank you for your kindness! hoping i could learn those new codes in the future.. there's so many boastful programmers here underestimating other programmers knowledge hope you become successful someday! you understand my situation, thanks a lot!

Comment: you really helped me a lot 100% working :) thank you

Comment: @AzeRonquillo Thanks for the comment and also for the code feedback. I am sure you can learn coding soon. There are many "boastful programmers" here but please don't be offended, at the end of the day we are all here to help each other :). Again Thanks for the kind comment. So nice to have you here. All the best! :)